# Type of copying takes place when = is used to assigned one object to other

Tags: java

Why is the output of the last statement `1010`? Which type of copying is this? Deep or Shallow?

```
public class P {
    int k;
    public P() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        P p = new P();
        P p1 = new P();
        p1.k = 4;
        p.k = 3;
        System.out.println("" + p1.k + p.k);
        p1 = p;
        System.out.println("" + p1.k + p.k);
        p.k = 9;
        p1.k = 10;
        System.out.println("" + p1.k + p.k);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't assign one object to another because `P p` and `P p1` are references, not objects.  You can only assign a reference from one to another.

Comment: But indirectly i am assigning object to the reference because if i write P p1,p2;p1=p2; it will throw an error...

Comment: You are assigning a reference to another reference.  You get an error because the reference you are assigning has not been initialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are working with object references. The statement `p1 = p` makes `p1` refer to the same object as `p`. That's why you get the output `1010`: because you edit the object that `p1` is a reference to, which is the same object as the one `p` is a reference to.

Consider this illustration. Before `p = p1` the `p1` refers to `o2` (black arrow). After the statement, it refers to `o1` (red arrow).

[image: Object References]

As for finding out if this is a deep or shallow copy, you can easily test it yourself.
Create a class that contains an object reference: let's say the class `A`.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        P p = new P(3);
        P p1 = new P(4);
        A a = new A(p);
        A a1 = new A(p1);
        System.out.println("a:  " + a.p.k);
        System.out.println("a1: " + a1.p.k);
        a1 = a;
        System.out.println("a:  " + a.p.k);
        System.out.println("a1: " + a1.p.k);
    }
}

class A {
    public P p;

    public A(P p) {
        this.p = p;
    }
}

class P {
    public int k;

    public P(int k) {
        this.k = k;
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
a:  3
a1: 4
a:  3
a1: 3
```

This means it's a shallow copy.

Comment: I know it,but does that mean it is deep copy?

Comment: It's not a copy, it means that kid_p1 wants the kid_p toy(o1). It's not a toy copy, it's the other's toy.

Comment: Ya i got it,but the question is when i write p=p1 which type of copying is this:shallow or deep?It was asked in interview.

Comment: I am updating my answer with a reasoning how you can find out why it is a shallow copy.

Comment: @Daredevil. Sounds like either a poor or a trick interview question. You could say it's the shallowest of all shallow copies: it only copies the reference. There is no object copying taking place.

Comment: I'm glad I helped. I see you are new to StackOverflow so here's a small recommendation: if an answer has solved your problem, click the checkmark next to it to accept it as a solution. This allows future visitors of this page to easily see which answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning, you had 2 objects, let's name them o1 and o2. p was pointing to o1, p1 to o2.

`p1=p;` means that p1 will point to the object pointed by p. So, p will keep pointing to o1, but p1 will also point to o1. (Side note: o2 is eligible to be garbage collected at this point).

When you modify p or p1, you are actually modifying the object o1. That's why `p.k=9;` is `replaced` by `p1.k=10;` because it means that o1.k will hold 9 and o1.k will hold 10.

Hope that helps.